# A question about minimal rational surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a minimal rational surface. We can find a smooth rational curve $C$ with $C^2\ge 0$ [Complex Algebraic Surfaces, Beauville,p59]. Further more we assume that $C^2=m$ is minimal and $C.H$ minimal for $C^2=m$.( $H$ is an ample divisor on $S$) 
Let $C_0\in|C|$, my question is :

1) Why $|C|$ is base point free?

2) When $\dim|C|=3$,$|C|$ determines a morphism $f:S\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$. Why for every $p\in S$ the fiber $f^{-1}(p)$ is the intersection of two distinct rational curves in $|C|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $S$ is rational, $H^1(S,\mathcal{O}_S)$ vanishes. Accordingly, $H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(C)) \to H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_{C}(C))$ is surjective. So the base locus of $|\mathcal{O}_S(C)|$ is contained in that of $|\mathcal{O}_{C}(C)|=|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1}(m)|$. But $|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbf{P}^1}(m)|$ is base point free as $m \ge 0$.

For your second question, if $C \subset S$ is a smooth rational curve satisfying your assumption on the intersection number, then $\dim |C|$ can never be $3$: one has $\dim |C| \le 2$ and $\dim |C|=2$ if and only if $S\simeq \mathbf{P}^2$.

So I suppose you wanted to say $h^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(C)) = 3$. The image of $x \in S$ under $f : S \to \mathbf{P}H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(C))^\vee$ is the hyperplan of sections $s \in H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(C))$ such that $s(x)= 0$. If $y \in \mathbf{P}H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(C))^\vee$, chose $s_1,s_2 \in H^0(S,\mathcal{O}_S(C))$ generating $y$, then $f^{-1}(y) = V(s_1) \cap V(s_2)$. By definition $V(s_i) \in |C|$ and is a rational curve since $C$ is a smooth rational curve.